# Prometheus context deadline exceeded

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, amazon-eks, kube-prometheus-stack

I am getting an following error:

```
    Get "https://192.168.188.161:10250/metrics": context deadline exceeded
```

I am running `kube-prometheus  v6.5.3` in AWS EKS K8S.

I am using default config. What should be wrong? Or how can I debug it?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZlMq.png

Comment: That's a scrape error that indicates that the target isn't responding to the request. This could be because the URL is wrong.

Comment: Prometheus uses the `scrape_timeout` defined in configuration (default to 10sec) to define a deadline on target scraping. It seems your target exceeds this timeout, either because it goes through some network blackhole or because the target doesn't answer on time. The best way to debug that is to try to curl the target from your pod.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Context Deadline Exceeded - prometheus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49817558/context-deadline-exceeded-prometheus)